# How to Insert/Update if record not exist / exists with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, exists

I'm wondering what would be the best way to check if record exists and then run update statement or check if record not exists and then run Insert statement? Reason why I would need `if not exists` is because I'm inserting Account information in the table. In situation when we have to update I'm just looking for unique ID. In other case for the Insert I have to make sure that `email` or `username`do not exist in the table. Here is example of my query:

```
<cfset var isUser = structKeyExists(FORM, "frmSaveaccount_isuser") ? true : false>
<cfset var isStaff = structKeyExists(FORM, "frmSaveaccount_isstaff") ? true : false>

<cftransaction action="begin">
    <cftry>
         <cfquery name="saveAccount" datasource="#Application.dsn#">
            DECLARE @AccountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = CASE WHEN LEN('#FORM.frm_accountid#') <> 0 THEN <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_idstamp" value="#trim(FORM.frm_accountid)#"> ELSE NEWID() END;
            DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(50) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#trim(FORM.frm_firstname)#">;
            DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(50) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#trim(FORM.frm_lastname)#">;
            DECLARE @Middle CHAR(1) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="1" value="#FORM.frm_middle#" null="#!len(trim(FORM.frmSaveaccount_middle))#">;
            DECLARE @Email VARCHAR(80) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="80" value="#trim(FORM.frm_email)#">;
            <cfif isUser>
                DECLARE @IsUser BIT = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" maxlength="1" value="#trim(structKeyExists(FORM, 'frm_isuser')? 1:0)#">;
                DECLARE @ActiveUser BIT = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" maxlength="1" value="#trim(structKeyExists(FORM, 'frm_activeuser')? 1:0)#">;
                DECLARE @SystemAdmin BIT = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" maxlength="1" value="#trim(structKeyExists(FORM, 'frm_systemadmin')? 1:0)#">;
                DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(50) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#trim(FORM.frm_username)#">;
            </cfif>
            <cfif isStaff>
                DECLARE @IsStaff BIT = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" maxlength="1" value="#trim(structKeyExists(FORM, 'frm_isstaff')? 1:0)#">;
                DECLARE @ActiveStaff BIT = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" maxlength="1" value="#trim(structKeyExists(FORM, 'frm_activestaff')? 1:0)#">;
                DECLARE @Position VARCHAR(10) = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="10" value="#trim(FORM.frm_positioncode)#" null="#!len(trim(FORM.frm_positioncode))#">;
            </cfif>
            DECLARE @ActionDate DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
            DECLARE @ActionID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_idstamp" value="#AccountID#">;

            BEGIN TRAN
                IF EXISTS (SELECT AccountID FROM Accounts WITH (updlock,serializable) WHERE AccountID = @AccountID)
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE Accounts 
                    SET
                        FirstName = @FirstName,
                        LastName = @LastName,
                        Middle = @Middle,
                        Email = @Email,
                        <cfif isUser>
                            IsUser = @IsUser,
                            ActiveUser = @ActiveUser,
                            SystemAdmin = @SystemAdmin,
                            UserName = @UserName,
                        </cfif>
                        <cfif isStaff>
                            IsStaff = @IsStaff,
                            ActiveStaff = @ActiveStaff,
                            Position = @Position,
                        </cfif>
                        ActionDate = @ActionDate,
                        ActionID = @ActionID
                    WHERE AccountID = @AccountID
                    SELECT @AccountID AS RecID
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Accounts WHERE Email = @Email <cfif isUser> OR UserName = @UserName</cfif>)
                        INSERT INTO Accounts (
                            AccountID,FirstName,LastName,Middle,Email,
                        <cfif isUser>
                            IsUser,ActiveUser,SystemAdmin,UserName,
                        </cfif>
                        <cfif isStaff>
                            IsStaff,ActiveStaff,Position,
                        </cfif>
                            ActionDate,ActionID
                        ) VALUES (
                            @AccountID,@FirstName,@LastName,@Middle,@Email,
                        <cfif isUser>
                            @IsUser,@ActiveUser,@SystemAdmin,@UserName,
                        </cfif>
                        <cfif isStaff>
                            @IsStaff,@ActiveStaff,@Position,
                        </cfif>
                            @ActionDate,@ActionID
                        )
                        SELECT @AccountID AS RecID
                    END
                    COMMIT TRAN
                </cfquery>
                <cfcatch type="any">
                     <cftransaction action="rollback" />
                     <cfset var fnResults.status = "400">
                     <cfset var fnResults.message = "Error! Please contact your administrator.">
                </cfcatch>
             </cftry>
    </cftransaction>
```

I'm wondering if this is better approach then split in two separate queries insert/update? Also is there better way to check if record exists/not exists?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169973/discussion-on-question-by-espresso-coffee-how-to-insert-update-if-record-not-exi).

Answer (score 3):

The `MERGE` may be something along the lines of

```
MERGE Accounts tgt
USING ( SELECT 
            AccountID = 42 
          , firstName = 'Ted'
          , userName = 'ted'
          , email = 'ted@logan.com'
) src (AccountID, firstName, userName, email)
  ON tgt.accountID = src.accountID
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN 
  UPDATE
  SET FirstName = src.firstName
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  /* Check if username or email is already used */
  AND (SELECT 1 FROM Accounts WHERE username = src.username OR email = src.email) IS NULL
THEN 
  INSERT ( accountID, firstName, email, userName )
  VALUES ( src.AccountID, src.firstName, src.email, src.username )
OUTPUT $action, inserted.AccountID
;
```

As I said above, I'm not sure if `cfquery` can properly interpret a `MERGE` statement. You'll have to test that. You may have to make it a stored procedure call.

`OUTPUT` should return the type of operations it was (INSERT or UPDATE) and the `AccountID` associated.

EDIT: I created a Fiddle to demonstrate some of the different uses you're attempting here.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=710ea9d801637c17c88f27cac165a8f5

Although, to be honest, the more I thought about this, the more I thought that `MERGE` was more intended for bulk data upserts. The above method works, but it's a single row. It may be more efficient to just test for the existence of the requested record and then `INSERT` or `UPDATE` as needed. A `MERGE` may be overkill.

Comment: Shawn great example. Thanks a lot. Is there a way to check if Email OR Username exist before we run Insert statement? That's the last piece that I would like to check?

Comment: Just saw your further comment below about verifying that `email` and `username` don't exist before inserting. That'll require an additional check. I'll look at that. Do you have any sample data and schema I can play with?

Comment: Do you think that creating separate cfquery on the top of the function is better approach and then just based on that query result run insert or update? Also there is an option to check if form value `accountid` is empty. In that case we can run UPDATE with IF EXISTS or INSERT with IF NOT EXISTS. Does that make sense? I'm not sure if I need to use MERGE in that case.

Comment: One of the good things about ColdFusion is that it will take any T-SQL string. It will happy MERGE. As for running separate queries, the small problem with that is, you putting a load on the CF server AND SQL Server. If it was done to SQL Server only, you can get better scalability

Comment: "it will take any T-SQL string" Yep. The database itself determines whether a particular sql command is supported. CF's job is just to forward the sql strings and receive the results. I suspect what Shawn was alluding to is whether cfquery will properly process the results of OUTPUT. I can confirm it does with CF11 and SqlServer 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to 2008 the approach you are using is pretty much there. There's no "Upsert" in SQL Server that will take care of it for you so you must check yourself.

**Before 2008 - Generic**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [PrimaryKey] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [PrimaryKey] = @PassedInID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [MyTable]
        SET [Field1] = @PassedInValue1,
            [Field2] = @PassedInValue2
        WHERE [PrimaryKey] = @PassedInID
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([PrimaryKey], [Field1], [Field2])
        VALUES (@PassedInID, @PassedInValue1, @PassedInValue2)
    END
```

If you are making a lot of updates and calling this many times, either pass in the primary key, or index the value you are passing in. This will save SQL Server from loading the table data to know whether an insert update is needed.

However, if you are calling it many times, it would be better to pass in a table of all inserts/updates and `JOIN` on the existing table twice, and just perform one `INSERT` and one `UPDATE`

**2008 & Later - Sepcific**
With 2008 and later you can use `MERGE` (Thanks for @Shawn for pointing out it was that old)

```
MERGE INTO [Accounts] AS target
USING (SELECT @AccountID) AS source ([AccountID])  
    ON (target.[Email] = source.Email AND target.[Username] = @Username)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN  
        UPDATE SET [FirstName] = @FirstName
                , [LastName] = @LastName
                , [Middle] = @Middle
                , [Email] = @Email
                , [Username] = @Username
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT ([AccountID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Middle], [Email], [Username])  
    VALUES (@AccountID, @FirstName, @LastName, @Middle, @Email, @Username)
```

**All-in-one**
If you have to check the email and username as the same time, you could mix `IF NOT EXISTS` and `MERGE`

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [PrimaryKey] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Email] = @Email OR [Username] = @Username)
    BEGIN
        MERGE INTO [Accounts] AS target
        USING (SELECT @AccountID) AS source ([AccountID])  
            ON (target.[Email] = source.Email AND target.[Username] = @Username)  
            WHEN MATCHED THEN  
                UPDATE SET [FirstName] = @FirstName
                        , [LastName] = @LastName
                        , [Middle] = @Middle
                        , [Email] = @Email
                        , [Username] = @Username
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
            INSERT ([AccountID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Middle], [Email], [Username])  
            VALUES (@AccountID, @FirstName, @LastName, @Middle, @Email, @Username)
    END
```

Comment: What about `IF NOT EXISTS` before insert statement? I have to check if `email` or `username` already exist.

Comment: As of SQL 2008, there is a `MERGE` statement that is specifically made for upserts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Shawn Can you please provide example using `MERGE`?

Comment: @Shawn - I did not realise MERGE went that far back. Thanks

Comment: @Red Thanks for example. I'm looking at your code and maybe I'm not understanding but for the update we should be checking AccountID. If exists the run update. Then before we run Insert statement we should check if email or username already exists. If does skip insert do nothing. Does that make sense? This way we would make sure that unique Account ID is update and that we never end up with the same username or email in the table.

Comment: I see. I did not get that before. Do you really need to do this in 1 operation? I'd recommend a check for the email and username before trying the `MERGE`. I've updated my code, but Shawn may have a better answer with all your friends specified

Comment: @Red Two statements are fine if that would make things simple.

Comment: It would be recommended, but I've updated the answer to include if you have to or there's another reason it's better to do it at the same time

Comment: @espresso_coffee - Noticed you're using uplock. If concurrency is an issue, verify whichever option you choose handles it correctly. (Just wrapping the sql in a default transaction won't do it.)  [Apparently even single statement merge has had issues](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/), but concurrency is a whole another topic, probably better for dba.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 1):

(Too long for comments ...)

The other answers already answered the primary question. This post is to answer to your earlier question about how a stored procedure could streamline things.

Although using a cfquery is valid, personally I'd use a stored procedure instead. Procedures are better at handling complex sql and would also make it easier to take advantage of sql `NULL`'s and/or defaults to simplify the logic.

Instead of having a bunch of `cfif/cfelse` statements strewn throughout the SQL, create a stored procedure with all of the required variables. [Assign whatever default values you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189330(v=sql.105)) for the *optional* parameters. `NULL` is usually a good choice, because it makes it easy to detect omitted parameters and substitute different values with `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()`, but .. all depends on your app's business logic.

**Stored Procedure Signature**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourProcedureNameHere]
    @AccountID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    , @FirstName VARCHAR(50)
    , @LastName VARCHAR(50)
    , @Middle CHAR(1)
    , @Email VARCHAR(80)
    , @IsUser BIT = NULL
    , @ActiveUser BIT = NULL
    , @SystemAdmin BIT = NULL
    , @UserName VARCHAR(50) = NULL 
    , @IsStaff BIT = NULL
    , @ActiveStaff BIT = NULL
    , @Position VARCHAR(10) = NULL 
AS 
BEGIN
      ... your sql logic ....
END
GO
```

Then call the procedure from CF, using a single `cfif` to conditionally pass in the appropriate variables for either a "user" or "staff". Whichever set of variables are omitted (user or staff settings), will be assigned default values inside the stored procedure.

Few other suggestions about the CF code

- Like @Shawn said, most of the ternary operators aren't needed. Functions like `structKeyExists()` already return a boolean value. No need to do anything extra like trim(), etc.. to use the result with a CF_SQL_BIT column. It's converted automagically.
- Transactions are for multiple statements. Since the UPDATE and INSERT are atomic, the transaction statement don't really do anything. Least not with default transaction level.
- Since the code appears to be contained within a cffunction, don't use the `form` scope directly. Whatever values the function needs should be declared and passed into function using the `arguments` scope.

There's probably additional ways to streamline things but this should give you a good start.

**Sample Procedure Call**

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="YourProcedureNameHere" datasource="#yourDSN#">
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@AccountID" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" value="#arguments.frm_accountid#" ....>
    ... more params ...
    <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@Email" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.frm_email#">

    <!--- User --->
    <cfif structKeyExists(ARGUMENTS, "frmSaveaccount_isuser")>
        <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@IsUser" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="1">
        <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@ActiveUser" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="#structKeyExists(arguments, 'frm_activeuser')#">
        ... more params ... 
    </cfif>

    <!--- Staff --->
    <cfif structKeyExists(ARGUMENTS, "frmSaveaccount_isstaff")>
        <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@IsStaff" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="1">
        <cfprocparam type="in" dbvarname="@ActiveStaff" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="#structKeyExists(arguments, 'frm_activeuser')#">
        ... more params ... 
    </cfif>


</cfstoredproc>
```

Comment: This example of stored procedure should be inside of the `cffunction` I guess?

Comment: The `<cfstoredproc>` call replaces the cfset's and cfquery in the OP.

Comment: The stored procedure is created in the database itself with the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement. Run it in SSMS or whatever you're using to interact directly with your database.

Comment: And don't forget to give `EXECUTE` permission on the sproc in SQL to your CF user (or whichever user runs for your `cfquery`).

Comment: "The stored procedure is created in the database itself ..." .. and obviously should contain whatever SQL you decided on, MERGE or UPDATE / INSERT.